# LinearLayout to animate when shown

Tags: java, android

I have a vertical LinearLayout which has two another vertical layouts inside. The first one is always shown, and the second one depends on some event. I do want to animate that second layout when shown. How can I do it smoothly and nice? Thank you so much,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out this library on Github. It may help. It is an animation library for listviews.
[ListViewAnimations](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations)

Answer (score 0):

A very simple, yet elegant way to get your layouts animated is by using the `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` on its parent. This will likely take a lot of work in getting a nice animation out of your hands, unless you want to customize it.

With KitKat, Google introduced the [android.transtion API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/package-summary.html), which may also be worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `animation` and you apply that animation to your `layout` when you need(In your case at the time of shown your layout)

```
yourLayout.startAnimation(yourAnimation);
```